# How to test functionality that can only be accessed at the beginning of the next week?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, software-quality

Description:

I am currently testing an 8base application and I have encountered a problem with a specific functionality that can only be tested at the beginning of the next week.

Functionality:

The application has two types of users:

Questioners: who ask questions.

Answerers: who can answer questions only at the beginning of the next week.

Problem:

I can only test this functionality at the beginning of the next week. However, waiting for the next week to run tests every time is not ideal.

Are there any ways to solve this problem?

P.S. I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am asking for the sake of my project.

Comment: Is there any way to mock it being next week? How is "next week" defined?

Comment: For example, this week I can create questions that the user can only answer on Monday, 02/12/2024. Next week, I'll be able to create questions and the user can only answer them starting from the 19th, and so on.

Comment: It won't be possible to mock it, we need to somehow influence the date :((

Comment: The first thing I think of is using a high gravitational field so the differential time will come earlier, but the energy requirements... Maybe you could just programme in a date difference specifically for tests.

Comment: What if we make the questions last week in order to answer in this week? Not doable?